# Eclipse directory structure for class, test, and main

Tags: java, eclipse, package, directory-structure

Within Eclipse IDE: Suppose I have a custom designed class I create called Counter, I then create a simple Java application that contains and main and uses one or more of these Counter objects, e.g. printing output to the console. Further to this I decide to write some unit tests for the Counter class and so I have a Test Case class.

I propose calling the Test Case class CounterTest and the main method application CounterMain. Does this sound sensible?

Furthermore, in terms of getting a consistent directory structure for circumstances such as this I thought of having a source folder in my project called "src" containing a package "lib" that contains the Counter class. Then having another source folder called "test" containing a package "lib" that contains the CounterTest class.

I'm unsure of where would be best to place CounterMain, e.g. would you recommend placing it inside of a separate source folder called "main" containing a package "lib", so as to mirror the other package structure, or simply placing CounterMain in the same package as Counter?

I'll likely end up with a variety of individual classes each of which have an associated Main and Test Case class being in the same project, so I would like a consistent directory structure for these.

I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: This is completely opinion-based. If I could vote to close I would

Comment: If you follow a Maven directory structure, then you have `src/main/java` and `src/main/test`. Both main Java code and tests share the `lib` directory

Comment: eclipse has a good maven plugin. The maven build infrastructure handles libraries, versioning, testing and packaging. It is `src/main/java, src/main/resources, src/test/java, src/test/resources`

Comment: Sorry but taking my example classes, where do I put CounterMain, Counter and CounterTest respectively?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm wondering whether my main entry point classes should go in a different directory structure (and/or package) from the custom classes I create, or whether they should just sit in the same package?

Comment: Packages are different from source and test folders and are a personal opinion of organization for you, the developer